# Generating the tetrahedral element with nodal quadrature rule

Tags: acegen

By default, we do not have the possibility of using linear Tetrahedral elements with nodal quadrature in AceGen/AceFEM. But I suppose that there should be a way to construct it through the modification of the linear tetrahedral elements with Gauss quadrature. For example, for hexahedral elements, this can be easily done upon modifying the linear hexahedral elements using the SMSSign function in the shape functions as

```
Node\[Xi]\[Eta]\[Zeta] = {{-1 , -1 , -1} , {1 , -1 , -1} , {1 , 
    1 , -1} , {-1 , 1 , -1} , {-1 , -1 , 1} , {1 , -1 , 1} , {1 , 1 , 
    1} , {-1 , 1 , 1}};
Ni \[DoubleRightTee] 
  Table[1/8 (1 + SMSSign[\[Xi]] Node\[Xi]\[Eta]\[Zeta][[i , 1]]) (1 + 
      SMSSign[\[Eta]] Node\[Xi]\[Eta]\[Zeta][[i, 2]]) (1 + 
      SMSSign[\[Zeta]] Node\[Xi]\[Eta]\[Zeta][[i, 3]]) , {i , 1 , 8}];
```

Then by using the 2*2*2 Gauss integration rule (code 7), the integration points are transferred to nodes.
A similar way is not possible for tetrahedral elements because there is no SMSRound function that can be used in linear tetrahedral shape functions (knowing that abscissa is between 0 and 1). Is there any other way to do it?